# implement StackNavigator that is nested in DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My react-native app root is a DrawerNavigator. 
I navigate to each main screen with the drawer. In some screens, I also have buttons leading me to some other inner screens. For this navigation, I use StackNavigator. 
That is - I have a StackNavigator nested inside of my DrawerNavigator. But when I navigate to some inner screen, I have a gap at the top of the app, like this one: 
[image: App Snapshot]

Any ideas how o solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```js
export const StackNavigatorInit = StackNavigator({
    ScreenName: {
      drawerLabel: 'Screen Name',
      screen: ScreenName,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
})
```

Comment: That's it. The other option is to set header mode to 'none' which is more correct. A bit of additional description: the top header comes from stack navigation, see it here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#header , so you need to just hide it It's all.